# Why does the $Z$ gate transform $|1\rangle$ to $-|1\rangle$ but fixes $|0\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-gate, experimental-realization

How come that only |1> transforms to -|1>, while |0> stays the same? I see them as being "two sides of the same coin". I understand that only the global phase is affected, but what does the fact that |0> stays the same imply? A physical example would also be helpful

Comment: @Mauricio It's only irrelevant if your qubit is in either of the computational basis states, $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$. If it's in a superposition of the two it really is relevant, as it flips the relative phase of the qubit. As an example: $Z|+\rangle = |-\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should "see them as 2 sides of the same coin" - that's more a description of a classical bit rather than a quantum bit. A more appropriate analogy for a qubit would be the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere), where $|0\rangle$ occupies the north pole and $|1\rangle$ occupies the south pole.

However, mathematically it is pretty staright-forward (just matrix multiplication):
$$|0\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, |1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, Z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

So:
$$Z|0\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = |0\rangle$$

$$Z|1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = -|1\rangle$$

Comment: I get the mathematical explanation, but what does that imply physically? Why is the "north" pole different from the "south" pole, such that only one is modified?

Comment: The north pole is occupied with  basis state $|0\rangle$, and the south pole is occupied with the basis state $|1\rangle$.  The Bloch sphere is just a model of representing a state of a qubit.. Actually the basis states are orthogonal and not anti-parallel. $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are logical representations of physical states. The $Z$ operator acts differently on those states as @DaftWullie explained.

Answer (score 1):

At a practical level, it means that if there existed a controlled-Z gate, then applying this gate to |1> would give a phase kickback, in exactly the same way that a CNOT gate (literally a CX gate) has a phase kickback when applied |->.

Don't take the Block Sphere *too* literally.  Remember that antipodal points on the Bloch sphere, such as |1> and |0>, are actually orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Part of what worries you seems to be the asymmetry in action of the $Z$ on the states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. There's two extra things I'd like to add to the discussion in this context:

- You might be better thinking of $Z$ as $\left(\begin{array}{cc} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{array}\right)$. Again, it's all the same up to a global phase, but the action applies equally to the two basis states.
- Then,perhaps,one should go back to the beginning of what *is* $Z$? $Z$ is the operator that is designed to distinguish the two basis states, so it *must* introduce some asymmetry between them. Back at the physical level, your starting point is really that there are two different energy levels, separated by an energy $E$. That means it has a Hamiltonian in some basis of $-\frac{E}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right)$. This *defines* the $Z$ operator, i.e. the thing that distinguishes the two eigenstates.